# Collect 2 or more contract balances in one contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, ganache, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to develop a smart contract which collect fees from other contracts.

I tried to do:

```
function sendFees() public {
    address payable feeCollector = payable(feeCollector addredd);
    feeCollector.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

ad then I call the function like this:

```
sendFees();
```

But in ganache I didn’t see any balance change in feeCollector contract.
In feeCollector contract there is this function:

```
receive() external payable {}
```

which, in theory, should receive all fees sent.
I’m stuck and I can’t code anything else. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code as long as "feeCollector addredd" is replaced with the proper address. Maybe take another look at your setup?

Comment: You're right, Ganache has deployed the contract with feeCollector address 0x000... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `transfer` to send funds is discouraged and might cause problems in your case as the target is a smart contract (see https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/).

Additionally it might be helpful if you share any errors that appear in the console (e.g. in the transaction receipts)